# c# recursion  - "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute"

Tags: c#, recursion, ienumerable

I am trying to use recursion to go up a hierarchy, and i get this error:

```
Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
```

My assumption here is that when it enters the function each time, it is using the same parentRolesCopy and not a different one, so when it enters in the second time it changes parentRolesCopy to be different in the original function call.

How can I get around this?

```
private IEnumerable<string> GetAllParentRoles(string role)
    {
        // GET EACH PARENT ROLE
        var parentroles = //code that gets any parents of the role passed in


        //RECURSIVELY CALL THIS FUNCTION TO KEEP GETTING PARENTS OF PARENT ROLES UNTIL NONE LEFT
        var parentRolesCopy = parentroles;
        foreach (var parentrole in parentRolesCopy)
        {
            parentroles.AddRange(GetAllParentRoles(parentrole));
        }

        return parentroles;
    }
```

Comment: You're only copying the reference. They both point to the same actual collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the copy actually be a copy instead of just pointing to the same reference. One way would be:

```
var parentRolesCopy = parentroles.ToArray();
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! I didn't realize what I was doing was just making a reference to the original.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `List` or some other collection

```
var parentRolesCopy = new List<string>(parentroles);
```